# Number of occurrences SPARQL

Tags: sparql, semantic-web

Hi I'm using SPARQL to query the LMDB ( http://data.linkedmdb.org/snorql/ ) and I've been trying to also get the number of instances when some query results are returned. I've been trying to add `(COUNT(?something) AS ?somethingElse)` and then either `GROUP or ORDER BY` to my queries but then the variable `?somethingElse` replaces all of the other results. I think that the best way would be to use `UNION` and get the results in separate row, which has nothing to do with the others but for some reason I can't find the right solution.

My Query:

```
PREFIX mov: <http://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/movie/> 
SELECT DISTINCT ?Names  WHERE 
{ ?link mov:actor_name 'guy boyd' . 
?movie mov:actor ?link; 
mov:actor ?Link_To_Actor_Page.  
?Link_To_Actor_Page mov:actor_name ?Names.  }
```

If you run this query everything is fine but when if you add `(COUNT(?Names) AS ?total)` only `?total` is printed out. So I guess my questions is how can I print out as many variables as I want and get the `COUNT(?something)` as a separated column. Basically without the `COUNT(?)`replacing every other `?variable` in the query.

Comment: Of course, with no Group BY the total number of solutions is returned - what else? If you GROUP BY some `?x`, you have to select what you want to get back anyways. E.g. `SELECT ?x (count(?y) as ?cnt) ... WHERE { ... } GROUP BY ?x`. Note, the backend is D2R server, thus, no full SPARQL 1.1

Comment: @AKSW Yes you're right. This does fix my problem. I've already tried it earlier but for some reason I haven't noticed it. But say I want to count total number of occurrences of something else not this query but another one. Is there a way to print out the `COUNT(?x)` without the need to `ORDER BY` some variable ? LMDB uses this technique for such purposes.

Comment: @AKSW The key in this query is the last line 
`SELECT ?property ?hasValue ?isValueOf
WHERE {
  { <http://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/actor/39599> ?property ?hasValue }
  UNION
  { ?isValueOf ?property <http://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/actor/39599> }
}
ORDER BY (!BOUND(?hasValue)) ?property ?hasValue ?isValueOf`

Comment: I don't understand you. Why do you need `ORDER BY` if you do a `count`?

Comment: And I don't see what you're trying to achieve by the query in the comment besides getting data about a particular actor

Comment: @AKSW Do you know how could I print out the ?Names sorted by ?total from the highest to the lowest number i.e in descending order. I've tried with ORDER BY DESC(?total) but nothing changes.

Comment: Grouped by what? What is total? I need more input, neither your initial query, not the one in the comment contains this value. What is the general goal of the query?

Comment: @AKSW I'm asking about the original query in my question. I want it grouped by `?Names' and/or `?Link_To_Actor_Page` but next to next of these columns `'?total` number of times any given  name occurs. Then I want to limit it to 30 or 50 and still the the resulting query sortetd by `?total` not by `?Names` or  `?Link_To_Actor_Page`

Comment: The query would be `PREFIX mov: <http://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/movie/> 
SELECT DISTINCT ?Names  (count(?Link_To_Actor_Page) as ?cnt) WHERE 
{ ?link mov:actor_name 'guy boyd' . 
?movie mov:actor ?link; 
mov:actor ?Link_To_Actor_Page.  
?Link_To_Actor_Page mov:actor_name ?Names.  } 
group by ?Names
order by desc(?cnt)` but as you already recognized, there is a bug regarding ordering the data by an aggregate value.

Answer (score 1):

Morning,

Simply add what you need to the `SELECT` method. The number of asked elements is not limited.

Here is your example corrected :

```
PREFIX mov: <http://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/movie/> 

SELECT DISTINCT ?Names (COUNT(?Names) as ?total)
WHERE { 
    ?link mov:actor_name 'guy boyd' . 
    ?movie mov:actor ?link ; 
    mov:actor ?Link_To_Actor_Page .  
    ?Link_To_Actor_Page mov:actor_name ?Names .
} GROUP BY ?Names
```

Here is the location of the SPARQL Endpoint : http://www.linkedmdb.org/snorql/

I hope it will help you and not simply give you the answer without understanding it.

Comment: Your query doesn't do what I want. It just prints out the total but `?Names` aren't printed out. It's exactly what I said that my problem is, it doesn't help at all.

Comment: `select distinct ?Concept (COUNT(?Concept) as ?total) where {[] a ?Concept}` works perfectly fine on Virtuoso DBPedia endpoint

Comment: Indeed it is only a partial answer because of the lack of `UNION`

Comment: Maybe you need to edit your answer. Also I don't query the DBPedia SPARQL endpoint but the LMDB SPARQL endpoint, whic hare 2 completely different databases.

Comment: Obviously it is not the same ^^ Just explaining you your error with another example. Understanding and improving are better then just getting the answer and saying thank you.

Comment: Do you know how could I print out the `?Names` sorted by `?total` from the highest to the lowest number i.e in descending order. I've tried with `ORDER BY DESC(?total)` but nothing changes.

Comment: Adding `ORDER BY DESC(?total)` AFTER (before won't give you any results) the `GROUP BY` will classify the outputs first by the Names then by the total in a decreasing way. Both the conditions need to be specified. Only the Total will give you "36" no matter the names is.

Comment: Is there a way enforce `ORDER BY DESC(?total)` and still get the desired results  with the corresponding `?Names`

Comment: At first glance, no. The COUNT is possible because of the GROUP BY. Asking to process a DESC on the result of the COUNT before even declare the COUNT is not possible. Perhaps is there a mind trick that I don't know yet.